# Is the UdpClient.Available property exclusive to messages received on the port and IP address specified by UdpClient.Connect?

Tags: c#, udpclient

I have a query about the behaviour of UdpClient.

Consider I create a UdpClient and bind it to a specific remote IP address and port using the Connect method:

```
controlClient1 = new UDPClient();
controlClient1.Connect(TargetIP1, ControlPort);
```

I then create a second UdpClient and bind it to a different remote IP address but the same port:

```
controlClient2 = new UDPClient();
controlClient2.Connect(TargetIP2, ControlPort);
```

Will `controlClient1.Availble` return the number of messages received from `TargetIP1` only?

Many Thanks.

Comment: Of course the clients are independent. If not how could you reliably program if any other code running on the box would mess up your data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it will report only the number of bytes available to read in that client object. Refer [UDPClient](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.udpclient.available%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)